# How to store a HTML dropdown (<select>) in localStorage with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm very new to javascript, and am creating a basic HTML file. Basically, I there is a dropdown with no options, and the options will be created when the user fills in a text field and presses the 'Create Option' button. Any number of options can be created this way, and when the 'Add' button is pressed the current option which the user has clicked will be displayed in another line.
All that I have achieved with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><div id="name"><select id="sel"></select><input class="auto-save" id="inputname">
  <button id="button" onclick="newnamefunc()">Create Option</button><button onclick="wr()">Add</button></div><p id="paragraph"></p>
    <script>
        
        const input = document.getElementById('inputname')
        
        function newnamefunc() {
            const inputval = document.getElementById('inputname').value;
            const createname = document.createElement("option");
            const namevalue = document.createTextNode(inputval);
            createname.appendChild(namevalue);
            
            const element = document.getElementById("sel");
            element.appendChild(createname);            
        }
    
    
    function wr(){
        const selectel = document.querySelector('#sel');
        const p = selectel.value;
        const pvalue = document.querySelector('#paragraph').textContent
            = p;    
    }
    
    </script>
</html>
```

but what i want is when the user clicks a save button

```
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

all the created options will be stored in localStorage, and if a user reloads the page, the options created by the user in the dropdown before reloading will still be displayed.
I am new to programming, so if possible plain javascript. If libraries are necessary, please tell me how to implement them in my code.
any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must be use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

This method has setItem(), getItem(), removeItem() and clear()

```
miStorage = window.localStorage;
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Juan');
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Lautaro Zarandan thank you, but if you can please can you post it in context to my code? I cant exactly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

bellow code can help you!

```js
function save () {
  var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
  var opts = sel.options;
  var dat = Array.from(opts).map(opt => {
    return {
      text: opt.textContent,
      value: opt.value,
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("selectOptions", JSON.stringify(dat))
}

function load () {
  var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
  var opts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectOptions"));
  opts.forEach(opt => {
    var optEl = document.createElement("option");
    optEl.textContent = opt.text;
    optEl.value = opt.value;
    sel.appendChild(optEl);
  });
}
```

call `save()` when button Save clicked. When document ready,call `load()`!!

Comment: Thanks, but, umm, what exactly do you mean by when the document is ready?

Comment: it í `document.onload` or `window.onload` event!